# Implicit conversion regarding constness in c++

Tags: c++, type-conversion, constants, implicit-conversion

```
#include <iostream>
int foo(const char* keke) {
  std::cout << keke;
  return 0;
}
int main()
{
  char* keke = new char(10);
  char* const haha = keke;
  return foo(haha);
}
```

Why there is no any errors/warning while compiling the above code?

The type of `haha` is `char* const`, while `foo` only receive argument of type `const char*`. Could `char* const` implicit convert to `const char*`?

Comment: I reopened the question since it's asking about the implicit conversion, not the difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. It's called [qualification conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Qualification_conversions) (one of the implicit conversions):

(emphasis mine)

> A prvalue of type pointer to cv-qualified type T can be converted to a prvalue pointer to a **more cv-qualified** same type T (in other words, constness and volatility can be added).
>
> "More" cv-qualified means that
>
> a pointer to unqualified type can be converted to a pointer to const;
> ...

It means `char*` could be implicitly converted to `const char*`.

`const` qualifier on the pointer itself doesn't matter here, the parameter `keke` itself is declared to be passed by value, it's fine the argument to be copied from `haha` (i.e. the `const` pointer; `char* const`).

Comment: is there any implict conversion involved in the function call?`it's fine` in `passed by value`...

Comment: @Jichao You meant from `char* const` to `char*`? No.

Comment: In function call, there is no need to do type match for `char* const` and `char *`?

Comment: @Jichao Think about `const int ci = 1; int i = ci;`, they're the same case.

Comment: @Jichao IMO we don't say conversion for this, we say assignment, like it's fine to assign `char*` to `char* const`, or assign `char* const` to `char*`,

Comment: Is there any reference for such circumstances. Why does the constness for non-pointer-type and pointer type behave difference?

Comment: @Jichao Because they're totally different thing. You might want to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1143262/3309790).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121323/discussion-between-jichao-and-songyuanyao).